# Trying to launch intent at end of PageViewer. App crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

So when the user swipes through each page, I want an intent to be launched at the end; to show the main activity. Right now I set the number of pages to be 4 so that when the user swipes to the 4th page, the user gets sent to my main activity. However my app crashes

Fragment activity

```
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 4;

ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int pos = mPager.getCurrentItem();

    if (pos == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else mPager.setCurrentItem(pos - 1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


}


 private class adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 4) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.initialize(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

fragment

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

int position;

String[] text = {"Be more productive", "Choose your own work and rest times", "Login to access full features"};
int[] images = {R.drawable.productivity, R.drawable.workingguy, R.drawable.logincmon};



public static ScreenSlidePageFragment initialize(int position) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment page = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("POSITION", position);
    page.setArguments(args);
    return page;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = getArguments().getInt("POSITION", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.MainText);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.MainImage);

    tv.setText(text[position]);
    image.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return v;

}
}
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace of this crash?

Comment: `if (position == 4) {` this need to be 3, starting from 0..3 give you 4 pages

Comment: i think the way to fix this is to call some sort of outofbounds listener. However I am unable to find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the validation to start the `Intent` to 3, not 4.
Remember that lists start counting the indexes in 0.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if (position == 3) { // position 3 is the page #4

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    return ScreenSlidePageFragment.initialize(position);
}
```

The error that you receive is that you are calling `ScreenSlidePageFragment.initialize(3)`. In `ScreenSlidePageFragment` the `String[] text` and `int[] images` contains 3 elements (from index 0..2).

This will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at runtime and crash the app.

Comment: Doing that doesn't work. Because position 3 is out of bounds, I will never be able to swipe to get to that position. Is there like some sort of way that when I swipe out of bounds, the intent will be launched?

Comment: Why is out of bounds? Don't you have 4 pages?

Comment: I only have 3 pages. when i swipe to the 4th (which doesnt exist), I want the intent to launch. Thats why initially i set the page count to 4 so that when I swiped to the non-existent 4th page, the intent would run

Comment: Well, you need to have the 4th page, even it was a blank page. This method needs to return a Fragment when it reaches a new page

Comment: Alright. So im assuming there's no such thing as an outofbounds listener?

Comment: No, you can set the adapter to start the intent in page 3... Or creates a virtual fragment that show nothing, just to be able to launch your intent

Comment: try to put `finish()` after `startActivity(intent);`